# How do I create a file within a directory at the same time?

Tags: bash

so I know how to make multiple directories at the same time, for example..

```
mkdir -p tree/{dir1,dir2,dir3}
```

but how do i make a directory and put files in it at the same time? Ultimately I want to do this in many at the same time.

Comment: The commands for creating directories and files are different. There is no single command which will do both, though you can write a script which will do what you want with a single call.

Comment: show us what you have got so far, it's not immediately clear exaclty what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No single command exists to do this but you could make your own:

```
    mkpath(){ mkdir -p ${1%/*} && mkfile 0 $1; }
```

which can be called with a single argument specifying the path of a file to be created.  Any directories that need to be created along the way will be created, at which point an empty file is created with the specified filename, e.g.

```
    mkpath dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt
```

---

**Note:** *This is an example function that has not been thoroughly tested to cater for different inputs and situations.  Suitable error trapping may be required to ensure robustness.*

As it inherits the features of its component functions, `mkdir` and `mkfile`, two important characteristics carry over to `mkpath` as it currently stands:

- It appears safe to specify a path that includes pre-existing directories, and these directories and their contents will **not** be overwritten;
- Conversely, if a file exists at the location specified, it **will** be overwritten with a blank file and it will not be possible to recover the old file contents.

Comment: ok, thanks, sorry for the late reply, that is way over my head though

Comment: I guess what I am trying to ask is how to use mkdir and touch at the same time.

Comment: You can chain commands together in bash like this: `mkdir folder1 && touch folder1/file1` if that's what you mean ?  You can even create a 100 files with `mkdir folder1 && touch folder1/file{1..100}`.

Comment: ah yes! that's it!